# Plone website stops responding when cpu reaches nearly 100% even it can reach 400% as 4 CPU core are provided

Tags: performance, plone, cpu-usage, munin

CPU(s):  4 core

Thread(s) per core: 1

Sockets(s):   1

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post Plone related questions to our forum, https://community.plone.org

Comment: @piyush, please accept the answer. It's good practice.

Comment: Piyush, you can accept the answer by clicking the **`✔`** button in the left side of the answer.

Comment: its helpfull but not the exact answer as i am already using ZEO as a centralized database and running multiple Zope processes and multiples clients

Answer (score 5):

Python, due to its GIL, can only use one processor. Plone can run on multiple processors by using ZEO as a centralized database and running multiple Zope processes. You'll need to also install some sort of load balancer, to redirect traffic to those processes: nginx, varnish or haproxy can do that for you.

Comment: i am already using ZEO as a centralised database and running multiple Zope processes and multiples clients...... still cpu is underutilised to 1/4 and site is getting stuck/hanged.

Comment: Then you should debug the problem in detail. Try to associate it with a RAM graph, to see if the events are connected. Look in the traffic logs, to see if there's something that triggers the events. Look at the details ZODB cache logs, at memory swap usage, etc. Also, per other's recommendation, use the community.plone.org forum.